# How to put a delay of 5 seconds before posting message in a chat application?

Tags: jquery

I am developing a chat application where users can chat .

All this is working fine , i have got one more requirement which is how to put a delay of 5 seconds before posting each  message , as i dont want users to post continously ??

some part of my code

```
Chatbox.focus(function(){
    $(this).val(($(this).val()==searchBoxText)? '' : $(this).val());
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).val(($(this).val()=='')? searchBoxText : $(this).val());
}).keyup(function(e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);       
    if(code==13){
        $('.fixedContent').append("<div class='userwrap'><span class='user'>"+user+"</span><span class='messages'>"+$(this).val()+"</span></div>");
        event.preventDefault();

        $(".fixedContent").scrollTop($(".fixedContent").height());
        $(this).val('');
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aULsZ/64/

**Edited Code**

```
window.lastChat=0;

function sendMessage() {
    var enteredmsg = $message.val();
    if (enteredmsg !== '') {
        var now = Date.now();
        if (now - parseInt(window.lastChat) < 5000) //5000 miliseconds
        {
            alert("Sorry, no more than a message every 5 seconds");
            return false;
        }
        var msg = '{"message":"' + $message.val() + '", "sender":"' + $nickName.val() + '", "received":""}';
        wsocket.send(msg);
        window.lastChat = Date.now();
        $message.val('').focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Subtract of current time and previous time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach is saving the date/time of the last chat and check before sending a new one.

**Relevant code**

On page load, set a global variable

`window.lastChat=0;`

Then, when sending the chat, check the variable:

```
if(code==13){
    var now=Date.now();
    if (now-parseInt(window.lastChat) < 5000) //5000 miliseconds
    {
        alert("Sorry, no more than a message every 5 seconds");
        return false;
    }
    window.lastChat=Date.now();
...
}
```

Comment: Please see the Edited part in my question , where i have implemented your logic , but still i could post messages before  5 seconds .

Comment: no as this is dependent on backend code (websockets ) i am trying to make a replica .

Comment: missed the else block , working thank you very much .

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the chatbox after pressing the enter key, then enable it after 5 seconds using setTimeout

```
Chatbox.focus(function () {
    $(this).val(($(this).val() == searchBoxText) ? '' : $(this).val());
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).val(($(this).val() == '') ? searchBoxText : $(this).val());
}).keyup(function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
        $('.fixedContent').append("<div class='userwrap'><span class='user'>" + user + "</span><span class='messages'>" + $(this).val() + "</span></div>");
        event.preventDefault();
        Chatbox.prop("disabled", true);
        setTimeout(function () {
            Chatbox.prop("disabled", false);
        }, 5000);

        $(".fixedContent").scrollTop($(".fixedContent").height());
        $(this).val('');
    }

});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aULsZ/66/)

**Edit**

```
Chatbox.focus(function () {
    $(this).val(($(this).val() == searchBoxText) ? '' : $(this).val());
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).val(($(this).val() == '') ? searchBoxText : $(this).val());
}).keydown(function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
        if (!flag) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        $('.fixedContent').append("<div class='userwrap'><span class='user'>" + user + "</span><span class='messages'>" + $(this).val() + "</span></div>");
        flag = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            flag = true;
        }, 5000);

        $(".fixedContent").scrollTop($(".fixedContent").height());
        $(this).val('');
    }

});
```

[**Edited Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aULsZ/70/)

Comment: It's wrong. Using `setTimeout` does not mean: `Hey user, please wait after 5 seconds`

Comment: @Mr.Wolf Oh really? Common man, atleast think a bit. OP can tweak this code to work according to the need.

Comment: Yah. I'm sure. Because `setTimeout` means: `send this message after 5 seconds`. It's very very different from preventing user from sending next message.

Comment: `flag`. haha. I agree with you =))